# How to use Google Forms to accept 12 one-use codes for redemption of prizes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'd like to offer 12 one-use codes for redemption of prizes. I thought google forms would be a good way to accept entries, but I'm not sure how to limit entries. So far all I've come up with is that since google form has a time stamp for each entry, I know who was the first to enter the code. That might still be a disappointing experience for the potential second finder.

I found formLimiter (https://sites.google.com/a/newvisions.org/scripts_resources/add-ons/formlimiter) which automatically sets Google Forms to stop accepting responses after a spreadsheet cell contains a specified value. However I don't want to shut off Google Forms when the first of the 12 codes is used.

Any thoughts on a workaround, or should I be looking at other tools to accept validation codes? Thanks for reading!

Edit: The validation codes are secret so I can not list them in the form. The code must be physically found (in a geocache) to win a prize.

Comment: Choice Eliminator can remove an option.  So you could put all the codes in a list and users would have to select their code form the list.

Answer (score 0):

Only possible if people dont answer too close to each other and if you are willing to deal sometimes with a repeated code used.
Take a look at onFormSubmit trigger. From there you can edit the form (see the api for building forms https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/ ) to remove each code as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to script it, you could adjust the validation rules onFormSubmit.  Basically each time a user submits, it looks at the code used, then removes it from the validation rule of a text box.

If you can put the codes into a list, and have users select from that list then take a look at the Choice Eliminator add-on.